# Jira- creating one issue but have it in two projects

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I need to be able to create a Jira issue. but when selecting a project to add the issue too, i need to be able to add it to another project also. 
So what i have is the same issue, which can be worked on by both project teams.

I don't need clone or link as this results in two issues being created and needing to be maintained.

Does anyone have any ideas on how i might go about his? Develop new plugin perhaps?

Comment: Managing two issues for me is not a problem, so please dont call me lazy, its not helpful. however the situation in our company shows that there will be a large number of issues which may be worked on by different project teams at different times. Hence the need to edit just one issue, not two. Which is time consuming and eats into more productive work.

Comment: Why don't you just have one issue and then move it to the other project when it is being worked on there? You could have a placeholder in the other project pointing towards it.

Comment: @KeithC I didn't call you lazy, I asked if you are (hence the `?`). Most developers take being lazy as a good trait (ie DRY). What I don't understand is why you have projects separated by team. IMHO the projects needs to be coupled to the source code repository so that you can see changes associated with the bug being fixed. I too have had the issue of wanting to file multiple bugs but its because of downstream dependent projects (ie a dependency or library) not because I have two different teams that may work on the issue.

Comment: @AdamGent Its ok, I have investigated with some plugins. Exocet plugin, https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.valiantys.jira.plugins.exocet.jira-plugin-exocet seems to be able to provide enough functionality for me. While it does create two separate issues, it contains a synchronizer to allow changes in one issue be reflected in the other. Now all i have to do is configure it to my needs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using the [Script Runner add-on](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner), just add a script to the `create` transition that will create the same issue on the other project.

code for the script (change all id's to your own):

```
from com.atlassian.jira.util import ImportUtils
from com.atlassian.jira import ManagerFactory
from com.atlassian.jira.issue import MutableIssue
from com.atlassian.jira import ComponentManager
from com.atlassian.jira.issue.link import DefaultIssueLinkManager
from org.ofbiz.core.entity import GenericValue;

# get issue objects
issueManager = ComponentManager.getInstance().getIssueManager()
issueFactory = ComponentManager.getInstance().getIssueFactory()
authenticationContext = ComponentManager.getInstance().getJiraAuthenticationContext()
issueLinkManager = ComponentManager.getInstance().getIssueLinkManager()
customFieldManager = ComponentManager.getInstance().getCustomFieldManager()
userUtil = ComponentManager.getInstance().getUserUtil()
projectMgr = ComponentManager.getInstance().getProjectManager()
customFieldExample = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("custom Field Example")

# define new issue
issueObject = issueFactory.getIssue()
issueObject.setProject(projectMgr.getProject(10000)) # set which project
issueObject.setIssueTypeId("1") # which issue type
# set issue attributes
issueObject.setSummary("[copy from ...] "+issue.getSummary())
issueObject.setAssignee(userUtil.getUserObject("John"))
issueObject.setReporter(issue.getAssignee())
issueObject.setDescription(issue.getDescription())
issueObject.setCustomFieldValue(customFieldExample, issue.getCustomFieldValue(customer_email))
issueObject.setComponents(issue.getComponents())
# Create new issue 
newIssue = issueManager.createIssue(authenticationContext.getUser(), issueObject)
# Link parent issue to the new one
issueLinkManager.createIssueLink(issueObject.getId(),issue.getId(),10003,1,authenticationContext.getUser()) # change to your link id 
# Update search indexes
ImportUtils.setIndexIssues(True);
ComponentManager.getInstance().getIndexManager().reIndex(newIssue)
ImportUtils.setIndexIssues(False)
```